# NumberFormatException for input string: "1"

Tags: java, exception, numberformatexception

**NumberFormatException**
All values of splitData[0] are numbers. What could be the reason for the error? yearlyData is an ArrayList containing data separated by ";" . Example : 1;FALSE;46200

```
yearlyData.forEach((year, data) -> {
    System.out.println("Year - " + year);
    for (String s : data){
        String[] splitData = s.split(";");
        int foo = Integer.parseInt(splitData[0]);
        System.out.println(foo);
        if(splitData[2].equals("FALSE")){
            System.out.println(" - FALSE : " + splitData[2]);
        } else { 
            System.out.println(" - TRUE : " + splitData[2]);
        }
    }
});
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:668)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:786)
    at YearlyReport.lambda$report$0(Main.java:166)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421)
    at YearlyReport.report(Main.java:161)
    at CheckData.checkYearFileBeenRead(Main.java:235)
    at Main.main(Main.java:29)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: All other data under index 0 in the spliData does not cause an exception.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies not with your code but with the input data.

Was able to replicate your error with this sample input:
""1";FALSE;46200"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "\"1\";FALSE;46200";
        String[] splitData = s.split(";");
        int foo = Integer.parseInt(splitData[0]);
        System.out.println(foo);
        if(splitData[2].equals("FALSE")){
            System.out.println(" - FALSE : " + splitData[2]);
        } else {
            System.out.println(" - TRUE : " + splitData[2]);
        }
    }
```

- It seems you need to pre-process the data to remove " from the start and end of the number string.

Comment: splitData[0] contains a number. There are no "
before the number and after. Your error looks like this:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""1""`
compare your exception with mine.